# If $B\not\prec A$, does $A\preceq {\cal P}(B)$ or $A\preceq {\cal P}{\cal P}(B)$, etc in ${\sf ZF}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I've heard it said that theorems based on choice are also available in ZF "a few powersets away", and I think this is one of them, but I'm not sure how to prove it. (I'm also interested to hear of other formulas of this type. A special case: If $A\not\prec\omega$, then $\omega\preceq{\cal PP}(A)$, i.e. the double powerset of a Dedekind-finite set is infinite. This one I can prove though.)

**Edit:** Just to be clear, we say $A\preceq B$ if there exists an injection $f:A\to B$, and $A\prec B$ if $A\preceq B$ and $B \mathrel{\diagup\hskip{-1em}\preceq} A$.

To make the statement precise, what I am asking is if there exists an $n\in\omega$ such that

$${\sf ZF}\vdash \forall A,B[A\prec B\vee B\prec{\cal P}^n(A)],$$

and if so, what is the smallest such $n$. Andres' comment below suggests another, much weaker generalization: is the statement $\exists\alpha\in{\sf On}\,\forall A,B\,(A\prec B\vee B\prec{\cal P}^\alpha(A))$ provable? Here ${\cal P}^\alpha(A)$ is defined by transfinite recursion: ${\cal P}^0(A)=A$, ${\cal P}^{\alpha+1}(A)={\cal P(P}^\alpha(A))$, and ${\cal P}^\alpha(A)=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}{\cal P}^\beta(A)$ for limit ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\prec,\preceq$ exactly? I'm guessing the existence of an injection, but you may want to state that in clear terms.

Comment: @user14111 There is no injection from $A$ into $B$.

Comment: Mario: $\omega\prec\mathcal P^2(A)$, but $\mathcal P(A)$ could still be Dedekind finite. The neat thing is that, even if $\omega\not\prec\mathcal P(A)$, we anyway have $\mathcal P(\omega)\preceq\mathcal P^2(A)$.

Comment: @user14111 Yes, since $\preceq$ is a partial order, I suppose it would be natural to have $A\not\prec B$ literally mean that either $A$ does not inject into $B$, or else $A\sim B$. Sure, we should probably use $A\not\preceq B$, to avoid confusion. (And yes, I think $\prec$, etc, is standard notation.)

Comment: Mario: This is definitely not "elementary". (And you may want to fix the typo of the missing power-set in line 3.)

Comment: @user14111: The use of $\prec$ is fairly standard when talking about sets and not cardinals. That is, $A\prec B$ if and only if $|A|<|B|$.

Comment: Mario, it is unclear to me what do you mean exactly. Do you want to know whether or not in $\sf ZF$ the following statement is true: Given $A,B$ then there exists some $n$ such that $A\prec\mathcal P^n(B)$ or $B\prec\mathcal P^n(A)$. Or something like that? It's a very difficult question, and we know so very little about the structure of cardinals without choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would be happy with having a fixed $\alpha$, even if infinite, such that $B\not\preceq A$ gives $A\preceq\mathcal P^\alpha(B)$.

Comment: @Andres: Yes, that's a good question. I think that if SVC holds then it might be provable, but it stands to reason that one can cook up a crazy model where for every $\alpha$ there is a counterexample. That's probably a very difficult task, though. I'm not sure how to control transfinite power-sets from the ground model, but it is related to a lot of things I'm working on, so maybe in a couple of years...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, my question was whether we could prove that $A\prec B$ or $B\prec {\cal P}^n(A)$ for some fixed $n$ that depends on the proof (probably 3 or 4). I would think it should be a modification of the proof of Hartogs' lemma, but apparently it is a more complicated question than I thought.

Comment: @Mario: I am looking for mathematical quotes to get me started with writing something, and one of them is by Polya "*There are many questions which fools can ask that wise men cannot answer.*" This is particularly true for this sort of questions. There is little we can tell about the structure of cardinals without the axiom of choice. And it is quite easy to formulate good questions, but often it is very difficult to come up with proofs or examples. I'll give it some thought about whether or not one can manufacture a counterexample (at least for finite $n$'s).

Comment: Also, you may want to clarify some more on your question. It is provable in $\sf ZFC$ that there are $A$ and $B$ such that $B\nprec A$ and for every $n$, $B\nprec\mathcal P^n(A)$. For example, take $A=\omega$ and $B=\beth_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: Please clarify again. Where do the quantifiers on $A$ and $B$ lie?

Comment: @Andres: This looks very much like the Tarski-Feldman-Orhon-Blass theorem, and in particular the construction of finite antichains, isn't it? This may provide a proof for the finite case, if anything.

Comment: @AsafKaragila (Re: "Also, you may...") Yes, but that's not the theorem. Your theorem only says that the partial order of sets is "not archimedean" with respect to the powerset operation as successor, but mine says that any two sets are "eventually comparable", since the $A$ and $B$ are switched in the two clauses of the statement.

Comment: Mario, my quantifiers are located differently: There is an $\alpha$ such that for every $A,B$ ... Else, this is trivial, since any $A,B$ belong to some $V_\alpha=\mathcal P^\alpha(\emptyset)$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Fair enough. My intuition tells me, though, that if a universal statement for all $A,B$ cannot be found among finite $n$, or maybe $\alpha=\omega$, then there is no ordinal $\alpha$ will do the job. What ordinals not dependent on $A$ or $B$ could possibly be so distinguished among all ordinals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative in $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$.

Let $A$ be a set which cannot be well-ordered, pick $\alpha\in\sf Ord$, and let $B=\aleph(\mathcal P^\alpha(A))$, then we have that $A$ and $B$ are incomparable, but also $\mathcal P^\alpha(A)$ and $B$ are incomparable.

Comment: Yes, OK. I figured there was something like this. Let's change the question: Can we find an $\alpha$ that works whenever $A$ is non-well-orderable, and $B=\aleph(A)$?

Comment: @Andres: $\alpha=3$? Recall my MO question (that you answered) about Hartogs and the Three Power Sets! :-)

Comment: Yes, that's not what I meant, sorry. I meant: Is there $\alpha$ such that for any such $A,B=\aleph(A)$, you can embed $A$ into $\mathcal P^\alpha(B)$?

Comment: Also, the original question should be symmetric: Is there an $\alpha$ such that, for any incomparable $A,B$, either $A\preceq\mathcal P^\alpha(B)$, or $B\preceq\mathcal P^\alpha(A)$?

Comment: @Andres: I'd suspect that the answer should be an equally easy of a "no". Maybe if I'll drink a lot tonight, the answer will be apparent in the morning, like this one was!

Comment: @Andres: It seems that the other direction would have to be an independent result. For example if the Kinna-Wagner principle holds then for any $\alpha$ there is some $\kappa$ large enough $\mathcal P^\alpha(A)\prec\mathcal P(\kappa)$. It might as well be $\aleph(A)$ too, by taking $A=A+\kappa$ and considering $B=\kappa^+$. Things get messy after that.